# Updates on a table must be inserted into another table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2008-r2

Is there a way to insert records into `TABLE B` if there is an update in `TABLE A`?

I don't want to use triggers.

---

The answer is we can use the `OUTPUT` clause of instead of triggers:

```
USE AdventureWorks2012;
GO
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.vw_ScrapReason','V') IS NOT NULL
    DROP VIEW dbo.vw_ScrapReason;
GO
CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_ScrapReason
AS (SELECT ScrapReasonID, Name, ModifiedDate
    FROM Production.ScrapReason);
GO
CREATE TRIGGER dbo.io_ScrapReason 
    ON dbo.vw_ScrapReason
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
--ScrapReasonID is not specified in the list of columns to be inserted 
--because it is an IDENTITY column.
    INSERT INTO Production.ScrapReason (Name, ModifiedDate)
        OUTPUT INSERTED.ScrapReasonID, INSERTED.Name, 
               INSERTED.ModifiedDate
    SELECT Name, getdate()
    FROM inserted;
END
GO
INSERT vw_ScrapReason (ScrapReasonID, Name, ModifiedDate)
VALUES (99, N'My scrap reason','20030404');
GO
```

Comment: you want to automatically insert rows on a table if some rows are updated, but you don't want to use triggers, is that what you are asking?

Comment: have a look at [OUTPUT](http://technet.microsoft.com/us-en/library/ms177564.aspx)

Comment: If you don't want to use a trigger, what's going to trigger what you want to do?

Comment: @Lamak yes i dont want use triggers is there any logging in SQL to stores  updates in a table.

Comment: @Kumar, yeah that can be done, with a trigger...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson can we do that without a trigger.Instead of trigger can we use any Logging on that table

Comment: If you can change the `UPDATE` query, then you can use the `OUTPUT` clause as @bummi mentioned. If you can't, then you need to at least consider triggers among your options. Why don't you want to use them? Why is there the beginnings of a trigger in your question?

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism for doing this is called `triggers`.

Saying that you want to do this but don't want to use triggers is like saying you want to see the Eiffel Tower, but you don't want to go to France.

You could, I suppose, write a stored procedure that does all the logic that would have been in the trigger, if you can **ensure that all data updates** will be via that stored procedure.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use triggers, then you would have three options.

The first would be to wrap all inserts/updates/deletes in stored procedures.  Then use only these stored procedures for data modification.  This is actually the approach that I generally take.

Another would be to have a process that runs periodically looking for changes to the data.  This is actually hard to do for updates.  It is pretty easy to do for inserts because you can add an column with a default creation date, so you can readily find what has recently been added.

The third way is to use SQL Server Change Tracking (see [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb933875%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)).

Answer (score 0):

You could make a stored procedure that performs both the update in table A and the insert in table B

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name
    @id
    @param1
AS
BEGIN
    update tableA
    set field1 = @param1
    where ID = @id

    insert into tableB(field1)
    values(@param1)

END
```